# How to set max-width of dijit.ToolTip?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I tried the following, but it didn't seem to work.

```
var helpIcon = dojo.create("span", {"class":"help-icon", innerHTML:"[?]"}, td1);
var tooltip = new dijit.Tooltip({
        connectId: [helpIcon],
        label: "large paragraph of text here ... "
    });
tooltip._setStyleAttr("max-width: 100px");
```

Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Through experimentation, I found that this works:

`.dijitTooltip {max-width: 50em;}`

Comment: +1 Looks like you also discussed it [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/setting-max-width-of-dijit-ToolTip-td102038.html#none) on the Dojo forum? And got some support for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just put a div inside the `ToolTip` and limit it's width:

```
<span id="a">Some Text</span>
<div dojoType="dijit.Tooltip" connectId="a" position="below">
    <div style="width: 400px;">Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info 
    Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info 
    Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info 
    Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info Some Info </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that style modifications apply to all the tooltips on the page.
Dojo creates (when required) 1 common dijit._MasterTooltip object that holds tooltip's dom nodes, and all tooltips use it.
The following code adds custom css classes to the rooltips's container and connector.

```
if(!dijit._masterTT)
    dijit._masterTT = new dijit._MasterTooltip();
// Add a css class to the container
if(dijit._masterTT.domNode.childNodes[0])
    dojo.addClass(dijit._masterTT.domNode.childNodes[0], "classContainer");
// Add a css class to the connector
if(dijit._masterTT.domNode.childNodes[1])
    dojo.addClass(dijit._masterTT.domNode.childNodes[1], "classConnector");
```